# How to replace spaces with points at even positions in a line using linux command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file where I am trying to replace the **spacing** at even positions with two points. What linux command Can I use to do it?

I tried the following sed command `sed 's/\s/:/2'` from [replace nth occurence of string in each line of a text file](https://superuser.com/questions/143392/replace-nth-occurence-of-string-in-each-line-of-a-text-file) But it only replaces the second occurence.

---

## input

```
TEDL15_TRAINING_00018 2 0.047883321 6 0.041573718 7 0.020443868 8 0.035350464 11 0.026124746 16 0.035317142 22 0.014992127

TEDL15_TRAINING_00015 2 0.076135024 66 0.036367059 68 0.05614619 106 0.040146504 113 0.038728137
```

---

## output

```
TEDL15_TRAINING_00018 2:0.047883321 6:0.041573718 7:0.020443868 8 0.035350464 11:0.026124746 16:0.035317142 22:0.014992127
    
TEDL15_TRAINING_00015 2:0.076135024 66:0.036367059 68:0.05614619 106: 0.040146504 113:0.038728137
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your text is stored in a file named test.txt:

```
sed -e 's/ \([[:digit:]]\+\) \([[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]\+\)/ \1:\2/g' test.txt
```

Explanation:

Basically your input numbers have the following format (where _ represents a space):

```
_digit+_digit.digit+
```

So the above just look for this pattern, capture its groups and rewrite them by inserting a ":"

Comment: thank @redobot. The second command searched for Integer and floats and the replaces the space between them with :. It doesnt used the odd nor even positions right?

Comment: No, it doesn't use odd or event, analyzing your input it has the format I describe in the answer above

Answer (score 1):

There's an awk method but I'm not sure it's the best choice in this case:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)
     if (i==NF) {
       printf ("%s %s\n",$i,$(i+1))
       }
      else
       {
       printf ("%s %s:",$i,$(i+1))
       }
     }'
```

Looks a little ugly but works in your case.

Comment: so it looks for the odd positions in the file and it replaces them with **:**. I just tried it. it works good.

Comment: We're starting with counting the number of fields and processing them 2 at a time, then we present them 2 at a time except the last one that doesn't need to show the semicolon at the end an instead prints a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where perl is the more readable option.

```
sed 's/\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+/\1:/g'
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s %s", (i==1 ? "" : ":"), $i, $(i+1); print ""}'
perl -pe 's/(\S+\s+\S+)\s+/$1:/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using behavior of sed that don't take twice same part of a search pattern with `g` option

```
sed 's/^/- /;s/$/ /;s/\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\)/\1|\2/g;s/..//;s/.$//' YourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\s\S+)\s/\1:/g' file
```

This replaces throughout the line a space followed by one or more non-spaces followed by a space by a space followed by one or more non-spaces followed by a colon.